# Application startup failed after adding spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I added spring security to my existing web application(method level security).

1) SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.freelance.impl")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         System.out.println("CONFIGURE HTTP SECURITY");
       http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(authenticationService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

2) UserDetailsService implementation class

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRespository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        boolean userStatus = false;  

        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        if(userEntity.getStatus().equals(Status.Active))
            userStatus = true;

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole().toString()));

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails =
            new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userName, userEntity.getPassword(), userStatus, true, true, true, authorities);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

3) Controller class

```
@RestController
public class AccountRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR')")
    @RequestMapping(value= "/acc/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HotelDTO createHotel(@RequestBody AccountDTO accDTO) throws Exception{
        return accountService.create(accDTO);
    }
```

4) Spring security dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The application works fine without spring security.
 But after spring security config class is added, the application startup fails.
 
I just get the below error when the war is deployed to tomcat server.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.webadvisors.config.AppConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jan 16, 2017 7:48:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 16, 2017 7:48:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/services] startup failed due to previous errors
```

5) Container log file - localhost.log

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController' defined in file [E:\DEV\apache-tomcat-7.0.72\webapps\services\WEB-INF\classes\com\freelance\controller\AccountRestController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
```

I am unable to trouble shoot the error as I don't see any exception/error trace in the console.

1) What is wrong in the security configuration that is causing this issue.
2) Why is the exception trace not shown on the server console? How to capture complete exception trace?

Comment: @Dur It is working fine after exposing AuthenticationManager as Bean. But Now get this error - **An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext** when I submit the request to REST URL